# Create an array with js or jQuery during a each()

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm looping through item in my code in order to create an array like this:

```
var formData = new FormData();
$('.active').each(function(index, element) {
    formData.append($(element).data('name'), $(element).data('value'));
});
```

But how can I insert these datas in a new array to have something like this?

```
Array
(
    Array ( <= New array level I want to create
        [item1] => onepager
        [item2] => provided
    )
)
```

This is what I tried:

```
formData['datas'].append($(element).data('name'), $(element).data('value'));
```

Thanks.

Comment: _"datas"_, _"onepager"_... I've seen these words before. If you're also user [popol](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9933285/popol), please don't create multiple accounts

Answer (score 0):

That's not an array, it's an object. You assign to an object property using array index syntax.

```
var formData = {datas: {}};
$('.active').each(function(index, element) {
    formData.datas[$(element).data('name')] = $(element).data('value');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're sending this to a PHP script (the `print_r()` output is a giveaway), you can construct `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` keys that are interpreted by PHP as arrays using square brackets

```js
const formData = new FormData();
document.querySelectorAll(".active[data-name][data-value]").forEach(element => {
  formData.append(`datas[${element.dataset.name}]`, element.dataset.value);
});

fetch("your/php/script.php", {
  method: "POST",
  body: formData
})
```

This will appear as an array in PHP under `$_POST["datas"]`

Answer (score -1):

Consider this

`typeof(new Array("data", "hello"));`
`typeof(["hello", "there"])`
`typeof({"hello":"world", "try": "this"});`